# In Illustrator, possible to apply one layer to another?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have the following:

[image]

where the text "Panning" is on one layer, and the rectangular grey mask that covers it is on a different layer. I was wondering, is it possible that I can somehow apply the grey mask to just the text area, and not have the excess mask surrounding it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Righ click on the text and choose Create Outlines. Then select all letters and make a Compound Path (Ctrl+8). Then place the image under the compound path, select them both and make a clipping mask (Ctrl+7).